# Adding rows with multiplication

Tags: r

I've got data as below

```
ID X1 X2 X3 X4
A  3  4  5  6 
B  5  7  9  2
C  8  5  2  6
```

I need to add additional rows, which contains multiplication of selected rows. Data should be like below.

```
ID X1 X2 X3 X4
A  3  4  5  6 
B  5  7  9  2
C  8  5  2  6
AB 15 28 45 12
BC 40 35 18 12
```

How can I convert it?
Thanks, anba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: basic idea is that you perform the multiplications for subsets resulting in two temporary data frames and then bind the three data frames back together:

```
library(dplyr)

# first subset:
df1 <- df %>%
  filter(ID %in% c("A", "B")) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("X"), ~.x * lag(.x))) %>%
  mutate(ID = "AB")

# second subset:
df2 <- df %>%
  filter(ID %in% c("B", "C")) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("X"), ~.x * lag(.x))) %>%
  mutate(ID = "BC")

# bind original `df` together with `df1` and `df2`:
bind_rows(df, df1 %>% filter(complete.cases(.)), df2 %>% filter(complete.cases(.))
  ID X1 X2
1  A  3  4
2  B  5  7
3  C  7  5
4 AB 15 28
5 BC 35 35
```

**EDIT**:

Based on @Darren Tsai's very helpful pointer, we can shorten the code, thus:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  filter(ID %in% c("A", "B")) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("X"), prod)) %>%
  mutate(ID = "AB")

df2 <- df %>%
  filter(ID %in% c("B", "C")) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("X"), prod)) %>%
  mutate(ID = "BC")

bind_rows(df, df1, df2)
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A", "B", "C"),
  X1 = c(3,5,7),
  X2 = c(4,7,5)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it;s working!
(there is missing ) in the last line )

Answer (score 1):

A programatic solution agnostic to the ordering of the pairs could be:

```
row_comb <- list(c("A", "B"), c("B", "C"))

df %>%
 bind_rows(map(keep(combn(df[["ID"]], 2, simplify = FALSE), function(x) any(map_lgl(row_comb, function(y) all(y %in% x)))),
               ~ df %>%
                filter(ID %in% .x) %>%
                summarise(across(ID, ~ paste(., collapse = "")),
                          across(-ID,  prod))))

  ID X1 X2 X3 X4
1  A  3  4  5  6
2  B  5  7  9  2
3  C  8  5  2  6
4 AB 15 28 45 12
5 BC 40 35 18 12
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A", "B", "C"),
  X1 = c(3L, 5L, 8L),
  X2 = c(4L, 7L, 5L),
  X3 = c(5L, 9L, 2L),
  X4 = c(6L, 2L, 6L)
)

PROD <- list(c("A", "B"), c("B", "C"))

nm <- map_chr(PROD, paste, collapse = "")

fltr <- sapply(PROD, function(x) df$ID %in% x) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  set_names(nm = nm)

PROD_RES <- map(fltr, ~filter(.data = df, .x)) %>% 
  map_df(~summarise(.data = .x, across(where(is.numeric), prod)), .id = "ID")

result <- bind_rows(df, PROD_RES)
result
#>   ID X1 X2 X3 X4
#> 1  A  3  4  5  6
#> 2  B  5  7  9  2
#> 3  C  8  5  2  6
#> 4 AB 15 28 45 12
#> 5 BC 40 35 18 12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>